# Replace a text line based on a pattern in previous text line using regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

**Requirement:** Replace the text line occurrence of "url: http://some.web.com/GVH-JBoss.ear" based on a text in previous line i.e "GVH:" with a new text [say: url: ftp://new.web.com/new.ear].

**Example:**
Consider text lines as below:

   `GVH:
     url: http://some.web.com/GVH-JBoss.ear
     sha1: 7b7b797735822d411c288d14510e9e023001d3ae
   VID:
     url: http://some.web.com/VID.ear
     sha1: 2fcac8bdcfadcfc12f0a7dfef0bad01db5f8f8a8`

**Expected:**

   `GVH:
     url: ftp://new.web.com/new.ear
     sha1: 7b7b797735822d411c288d14510e9e023001d3ae
   VID:
     url: http://some.web.com/VID.ear
     sha1: 2fcac8bdcfadcfc12f0a7dfef0bad01db5f8f8a8`

I tried using python regex [re.sub() method] to achieve this:

`re.sub(r'\s+GVH:[\s]*\s+url:\s\w+.*ear', 'url: ftp://new.web.com/new.ear', line.rstrip(), re.MULTILINE)`

Other Regexes tried to match this specified pattern:

 `1. \s+GVH:[\s]*\s+url:\s\w+.*ear
 2. (\s+GVH:\n)?\s*url:\s+\w+.*ear$
 3. (\s+GVH:\n)?\s*url:\s+\w+.*ear$
 4. [(?<=GVH:\s).*url:\s\w+.*ear$]
 5. (?<=\sGVH:[\s\S])url: \w+.*ear
 6. [\s]GVH:[\s\S](?=(\s+url: [\w]\.ear)
 7. (^.*GVH:[\s]?$)|(^.*url:\s\w+.*ear$)`

With all these regexes, Was able to find the text of either of the lines only but not both.

All of them failed to capture and replace those lines of text.

Need help in this regard.

Comment: Is this a `yaml` file?

Comment: You're using lots of unnecessary square brackets that are making your regexes more complicated than they need to be. Use `[` `]` to enclose a set of characters, e.g. `[a-z_]` or `[\w\s]`. Also `\w` only includes alphanumeric characters and `_`, so it won't capture the `://` in your url

Comment: Yes, input file is a YAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print (re.sub(r'(GVH:\s+url:\s+).*?ear', r'\1ftp://new.web.com/new.ear', line))

   GVH:
     url: ftp://new.web.com/new.ear
     sha1: 7b7b797735822d411c288d14510e9e023001d3ae
   HVA:
     url:  http://some.web.com/HVA-JBoss.ear
     sha1: e3ec053c65af5ce134c469ebbe3d7da29995369f
```

Comment: Perfect!. `(GVH:\s+url:\s+).*?ear` This regex matches my requirement. Thank you @Sunitha.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `yaml` module.

**Ex:**

```
import yaml

with open(filename) as f:
    data = yaml.load(f)       #Read yml file

newVal = "ftp://new.web.com/new.ear"
data["GVH"]["url"] = newVal              #Update Value

with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(data, outfile, default_flow_style=False)    #Write Back
```

Comment: Yes, this serves the purpose without the regex. But the requirement is to replace the file contents using regex.

Comment: Works in case of PyYAML python YAML framework is used. But this requires user to explicitly install PyYAML in his machine before running this code